# Packing of consecutive cubes

Tags: recreational-mathematics, 3d, tiling, packing-problem

Using the [Ponting Square Packing](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PontingSquarePacking/), squares of size 1-49 can be packed in a 7x7 array so that the 25 interior squares are completely surrounded.

[image: ponting 49]

Another way to look at the above squares is with the following grid:

[image: Ponting grid 7]

Is there some similar method that allows cubes of size 1 to 125 to be packed so that 27 interior cubes are completely surrounded? If so, would the central section of cubes have a cross section similar to the following?

[image: central 125 section?]

If such a 3D packing exists and is extendible, what does the shape look like for a lot of cubes?  As an example, here are squares of size 1 to 2025.

[image: ponting 2025]

Comment: Explain something about how the package is formed.

Comment: In your figure, just $9$ and $16$ are "completely surrounded" ? What does mean for you "completely surrounded"?, please.

Comment: In the first figure, square 19 is surrounded by 26, 29, 33, 30. Square 30 is surrounded by 12, 27, 15, 26, 19, 33, 16, 34.